# Is there an error in this jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    /* fetch elements and stop form event */
    var submitData = $("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {
        /* stop event */
        e.preventDefault();
        /* "on request" */
        $(this).find('i').addClass('active');
        /* send ajax request */

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "recycle.php",
            data: submitData,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg){
                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {            
                    /* find and hide button, create element */
                    $(e.currentTarget)
                      .find('button').hide()
                      .after('<span class="following"><span></span>Recycled!</span>');
                }
            }    
        });
    });
});
```

I think there is an error in this jquery syntax and or it could be my php code, I cant seem to find it!!

this is the recycle.php

```
<?php session_start();
include_once ('includes/connect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$tweet =$_POST['tweet'];


  mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes SET user_note='".$_POST['tweet']."',dt=NOW(),recycle_id='".$id."', user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");



?>
```

and this is the html code

```
<form class="follow-form" method="post" action="recycle.php">
    <input name="id" value="$id" type="hidden">
        <input name="tweet" value="$tweet" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="btn follow" title="123456">
        <i></i><span>recyle</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you think that? Do you get an error?

Comment: You should indent your code properly -- it's extremely difficult for others to read as it currently stands.

Comment: i cnt seem to find it!!! thats why i asked a question? :)))

Comment: Fix the indentation on your code and you might get an answer.

Comment: @henry sorry about that, i will tidy it up a bit

Comment: @terver can u suggest how i should indent my code, im not very good at that sort of thing!! thank you

Comment: Try to indent each level of your code more than the previous level. E.g. `$.ajax({` is much indented, but its content like `type`, etc is not. I did it for you. Have a look at it.

Comment: I cannot spot a particular problem in your PHP code now, besides the usual security issues (you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` for user data).

Comment: oh okay, yeh i will add the security issue now thanks, i dnt know why its inserting nothing into the database!, i know the values are being posted because i checked with firebug!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `submitData` looks strange to me. You don't have to declare that variable and it will not contain the data of the form (I think `submit()` returns nothing, so `submitData` would be `undefined`).
I think you have to do:

```
$("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {
  //...
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "recycle.php",
    data: $(this).serialize(), // gets form data
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(msg){/*...*/}
  });
});
```

Reference: [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @felix, can i ask why the data is not going into the database, in my recycle.php, i checked firebug and the data is being posted, can i show my php script!! is thats alright with you

Comment: @getaway: You can edit your question and add the PHP code, sure.

Comment: @felix i have added the php and html code, i hope you can help me, this is a big thing for me, cheers in advance

Comment: @getaway: It could be that  `recycle_id='".$id."'` has to be `recycle_id=".$id."` if `recycle_id` is defined as number. Try to run the exact statement in e.g. phpmyadmin and see if it gives you any errors.

Comment: hahaha, im so stupid, i should get killed, i mispelled the recycle_id it was recyle_id in the database!! :)) thanks @felix GENIUS

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery you probably already know this, but if you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) it should show you any syntax errors.  Just a thought.

Comment: Well I don't think there are any syntax errors, so it's probably a case of an object being null?